# paranoid outgoing-whitelist firewall

Tags: firewall

it might seem somehow unusual,
but I would like to have a whitelist ip address list for outgoing connections in my firewall

it seem like afer 30 entries of ip-range the list was full,
unable to hold any more

is there a solution

like eg /etc/hosts.out.allow

???

Comment: How were you setting the IP range? `ufw`? Something else? 

Comment: I set the ip range in the command line with ufw.... how about a single "allow" command with a .txt as argument, where the firewall pulls the ips from that txt file ?